# How can I import relevant files from my successfully synced android studio to another machine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.4

I have successfully set up my android studio on my laptop. Gradle, builds, emulation all working fine. Now what I want to do is copy relevant files from my Laptop's Android Studio to the AS on my desktop computer. I want it to replicate the exact settings and dependencies of those in my laptop, so that I don't need to connect my desktop to the Internet again and so that things are set up automatically. I did the following:
* copied the .gradle directory
* copied the .Android directory
* copied the gradle directory to the install directory
But no success. How can I achieve this?